# Trouble to get login with Android to PHP using MySql Database?

Tags: php, android

I'm having trouble login into a MySQL database from an android app using a simple username. I need assistance to see what I might be doing wrong or if I'm missing something

here is my PHP code

```
<?php


require "myconnection.php";

$username = $_POST["username"];

$sql = "select * from Login where username like '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$response = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){


$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$username = $row[0];
$code = "login_success";

array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"username"=>$username));
echo json_encode($response);

}else{

    $code = "login_failed";
    $message = "User not found..Please try again";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode($response);
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I'm using volley for posting data from android

the code is like this

loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View view) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginForm.this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    //get the response from the server
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");

                    if(code.equals("login_success")){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    if(code.equals("login_failed")) {

                        CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                                .setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("Login Failed PLease Check Your Username")
                                .show();

                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Check Your Connection Settings")
                        .show();
                Log.i("My error", "" + error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("username", gotUserName);
                return map;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: What is the problem with the given code? What makes you think that something is wrong?

Comment: each time i try to login its not logging in its display the message Login Failed PLease Check Your Username

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? Have you checked whether the login data is transmitted properly to the webserver, such that you could rule out that the problem is within your Android app?

Comment: Some questions ; Why use LIKE in the query? Shouldn't the username be spot on? Also, the security here is horrible (SQL injection etc). But maybe this is just for testing?

Comment: You are not debugging it properly. Watch your android studio console and see what it returns when the endpoing/URL is hit.

Comment: thanks all i managed to fix it @Shahid i was not debugging properly you are right

Comment: @danny if you manage to solve your problem, please explain how so it may help others in the future

Comment: okay i had to rewire it and make it simple by not returning a json response in my android app but by returning the response as a simple string